# How to setup click events on results returned via ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am returning a set of links from the database via ajax, like so:

```
function search_friends() {
    who = $('input.search_term').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'lib/search.php',
        data: {who:who},
        success: function(data) {
            $('.search_results').html(data);
        }
        // dataType: 'json'
    });
    return false;
}
```

That will return something like:

```
<div class="search_results">
    <p><b>results:</b></p>
    user1 <a href="add_friend.php?pid=3" class="3">add friend</a>
    <br>
    user2 <a href="add_friend.php?pid=4" class="4">add friend</a><br><hr>
</div>
```

But as soon as the page loads (before the search is done), I have something like:

```
$('.search_results a').click(function() {
    alert('code');
});
```

But that doesn't work because `.search_results` div is returned via ajax.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements

Comment: i'd make the <div class="search_results"> a static div and put the results into it. so you can bind the events because it will always exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to bind event to elements that does not exists at the time of binding. You need to use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind click event with event delegation.

```
$(document).on('click','.search_results a', function() {
    alert('code');
});
```

#### Delegated events

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

You should use jQuery `on` for dynamic content.

```
$(document).on('click', '.search_results a', function(e){
 alert('code');
});
```